# Array foreach y consulta MYSQL con php

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Tengo este ejemplo de foreach con array, y lo que necesito saber es ¿como puedo introducir consulta mysql a este array?

```
  <?php 
    $cabecera=array("nombre","telefono","referencia");
    $luis=array("Luis García","645395715","Trabajo");
    $paco=array("Paco Salvatierra","625781225","Amigo");
    $sofia=array("Sofía López","664887221","cliente");
    $pilar=array("Pilar Martinez","674458115","familia");
    $agenda=array($cabecera,$luis,$paco,$sofia,$pilar);
    ?>
```

Escribimos primero los arrays secundarios, los cuales formarán las filas de la tabla, y después los insertamos como elementos del array principal.
Después los mostramos anidando dos bucles foreach, mediante el código html necesario, los mostramos en una tabla:

```
    <table border="1" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
    <?php  
    foreach ($agenda as $fila){
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($fila as $celda){
                    echo "<td> $celda </td>";
                    }
            echo "</tr>";
            }
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Introduciendo la consulta:

```
include("conexiones.php");
//la variable $link esta en conexiones es la conexion a la base de datos



$cabecera = array($link,'SELECT fecha FROM clase'); 

$datos=array($link, 'select * from alumno '); 

$agenda=array($cabecera,$datos);
?>
<table border="1" width="60%" cellspacing="0">
<?php  
foreach ($agenda as $fila){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($fila as $celda){
                echo "<td> ".$celda." </td>";
                }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Me sale error:

> Catchable fatal error: **Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\cuadernos\asistencias_areas.php on line
>   178**

Comment: Si $link es un objeto de conexion mysqli, entonces primero estás intentando imprimirlo como string en tu tabla html. Segundo, no se entiende si quieres ejecutar la consulta o imprimirla

Comment: Si te fijas al declarar la variable `$cabecera = array($link,'....')` declaras un array  no realizas una consulta, tienes que reemplazar `array` por `mysqli_query` y lo mismo para la variable `$datos`

Comment: No entiendo por qué motivo estás usando dos sentencias SELECT diferentes. Si quieres mostrar dos tablas relacionadas entre sí deberías ejecutar un solo SELECT que una las dos tablas mediante JOIN en las columnas que hacen de clave primaria y/o clave foránea en las tablas.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu conexión, a la cual habrás llamado `$link` en el archivo `conexiones.php` que estás incluyendo, **funciona bien**. Puedes ejecutar los procedimientos siguientes:

**A.** Consultar a la tabla
Para enviarle una consulta a la base de datos debes usar el método `query`, del objeto `$link` de `mysqli`, por ejemplo:

```
/*
 * Viendo más de cerca tu código, creo que no es necesario lo de $cabeceras
 * $cabecera = $link->query("SELECT fecha FROM clase"); 
*/

$datos = $link->query($link, "select nombre, telefono, referencia from alumno");
```

**B.** Obtener resultados
Para obtener los resultados de dicha consulta, hay varias formas de hacerlo, una es invocando el método [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que te permite obtener una fila de resultado como un array asociativo.

```
    $filas_cabecera = $cabecera->fetch_assoc();
    $alumnos = $datos->fetch_assoc();
/*
 * Si haces print_r($alumnos) obtendrás algo parecido a esto, si tu consulta funciona bien:
*Array
*(
*    [0] => Array
*        (
*            [nombre] => Juan
*            [telefono] => 7874736
*            [referencia] => Trabajo
*        ),
*    [1] => Array
*        (
*            [nombre] => Pedro
*            [telefono] => 87759403
*            [referencia] => Amigo
*        )
*)
*/
```

**C.** Leer e imprimir resultados:

```
    $strHTML= "<table>";
            $strHTML.= "<tr>";

//Tus encabezados
            $strHTML.= "<th>Nombre</th><th>Teléfono</th><th>Referencia</th>";
            $strHTML.= "</tr>";
//Tus datos
            $strHTML.= "<tr>";
//Verás que al usar $celda deberás poner entre [] el nombre de la columna de tu tabla, como ha sido devuelto en el array asociativo de más arriba

        foreach ($alumnos as $celda){
                $strHTML.= "<td> $celda['nombre']</td>";
                $strHTML.= "<td> $celda['telefono']</td>";
                $strHTML.= "<td> $celda['referencia']</td>";
                }
            $strHTML.= "</tr>";
        }
    $strHTML.= "</table>";
    //Imprimimos la variable que hemos ido concatenando
    echo $strHTML;


    /* liberar resultados después de leerlos*/
        $datos->free();
    /* cerrar la conexión */
        $link->close();
```

---

**Más info**

- [Consultas (query) en MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) en la ayuda de PHP
- [Todo sobre MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) en la ayuda de PHP

Comment: implemente en base al ejemplo de tu codigo pero lamentablemente me muestra el siguiente : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, explicando en tres pasos el procedimiento. Considero que no necesitas hacer una consulta sobre encabezados, para obtener el resultado que muestras en la imagen. Debes revisar la forma en que estás concibiendo el modelo de tu programa.  Saludos.